# Stripe webhook best practice

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

After we receive the webhook, we should return **2xx** response, prior of doing some additional logic in our backend.

> Your endpoint must quickly return a successful status code (2xx) prior
> to any complex logic that could cause a timeout. For example, you must
> return a 200 response before updating a customer’s invoice as paid in
> your accounting system.

They suggest here to first return successful **2xx** response, and then to do additional things in our backend. They consider this as best practice so there won't be a request timeout.

I don't see how is this best practice, since there is an obvious possibility were our system fails in updating the database for example, and we already returned successful response. That means that Stripe will not try to re-send the webhook later, and we will lose this information since our system didn't save it.

Are there an existing solution for this sort of problem?

Comment: Why would Stripe care whether or not your system fails to update the database? Your system returning a 2xx response is like saying "Thanks, Stripe, we got the webhook" - if, say, there was an error updating the database, what would be accomplished by having Stripe send the same webhook again?

Comment: Database update can fail for various of reasons (For example. network fail). So if we don't send 200 but 500 in that case, then Stripe will re-send the webhook later and database update can be successful in that try. So to answer your question, Stripe should care, since they also accept other responses, not only 200. They explicitly provide re-try in case you don't send 200 response.

Comment: Of course you can do it this way, but depending on Stripe to resend a webhook when your system errors seems to me like a pretty irresponsible way to deal with this sort of thing. Better imo to think of a 2xx response to Stripe as "we've stored the webhook's payload in memory (or dealt with it in another responsible way) and can deal with it from here, thanks Stripe"

Comment: Well, that is why I posted a question here. To see how other people would handle this sort of problem. "store webhook payload in memory" solution would be one way to handle it. Please add it as an answer and add some more description, for example how would you proceed later with that in-memory data in case that database update fails.

Comment: Here for instance they are storing stripe events in a queue: https://www.fingo.net/insights-blog/cqrs-approach-to-handle-stripe-api-events.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I contacted Stripe Support and they said that timeout for the webhook request is 20 seconds.

> The default timeout is 20 seconds. To determine if it's a complex
> query you would want to evaluate how long would writing to your DB
> take.

I couldn't find this information in the docs, so it's really helpful. 20 seconds is more than enough to save something to the database and return 2xx response.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I had exactly the same question. With the 20s timeout it makes way more sense now